# Is $I^n \not = I^{n+1}$ for all non-zero proper ideals $I$ of an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain

For $R$ a (commutative with 1) integral domain, is it possible to have $I^n = I^{n+1}$ for some non-zero proper ideal $R$? I realise that in the case of a Noetherian domain, we can apply Krull's to get that the intersection of all $I^n$ is 0, so if it stabilised say at $N_0$ then $I^{n_0} \not = (0)$ since $R$ is a domain, but I'm wondering whether it's possible to have a non-Noetherian domain where we do have this stabilisation. I suppose this would mean we need a "large" ring, and I've found these are quite hard to work with intuitively. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $R=\mathbb{Z}\left[x_{q}\right]_{q\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}}/\left(x^{q_{0}+q_{1}}-x^{q_{0}}x^{q_{1}}\right)_{q_{0},q_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}}$, $I = \left(x_{q}\right)_{q\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}}$; $I^{1} = I^{2}=I^{3}=\dots$

Comment: (Typo above: the “$x^{q_{0}+q_{1}}-x^{q_{0}}x^{q_{1}}$” above should read “$x_{q_{0}+q_{1}}-x_{q_{0}}x_{q_{1}}$”. P.s.: $R$ is an integral domain because its nonzero elements have a well-defined notion of “degree” in $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ generalizing that of the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$.)

Comment: Why not $R=\mathbb Z[X^q:q\in\mathbb Q_{+}]$?

Comment: @Rafi if you want to, feel free to make your example into an answer so that I can accept and the question doesn't remain seemingly unanswered.